# Saving from CMD to csv

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, export-to-csv

i am running a command

```
bitcoin-cli getblock 000000006a625f06636b8bb6ac7b960a8d03705d1ace08b1a19da3fdcc99ddbd > C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\test-log.txt
```

which saves the following data into a text file

```
{
  "hash": "000000006a625f06636b8bb6ac7b960a8d03705d1ace08b1a19da3fdcc99ddbd",
  "confirmations": 222193,
  "strippedsize": 215,
  "size": 215,
  "weight": 860,
  "height": 2,
  "version": 1,
  "versionHex": "00000001",
  "merkleroot": "9b0fc92260312ce44e74ef369f5c66bbb85848f2eddd5a7a1cde251e54ccfdd5",
  "tx": [
    "9b0fc92260312ce44e74ef369f5c66bbb85848f2eddd5a7a1cde251e54ccfdd5"
  ],
  "time": 1231469744,
  "mediantime": 1231469665,
  "nonce": 1639830024,
  "bits": "1d00ffff",
  "difficulty": 1,
  "chainwork": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000300030003",
  "previousblockhash": "00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048",
  "nextblockhash": "0000000082b5015589a3fdf2d4baff403e6f0be035a5d9742c1cae6295464449"
}
```

which is fine currently, but i will be running 500,000 of these commands

what i am trying to do is save just hash, size,weight, height in csv file

how do i do this ? - or does anyone have any links to explain how this is done ?

Comment: What have you tried so far, what do you have trouble with? Please regard that StackOverflow is not a free code/script writing service! So please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: Unix or Windows?

Comment: @access_granted, the tags [tag:cmd] and [tag:batch-file] indicate Windows -- see the tag infos...

Comment: Made it cross-platform. This will run on Unix and on Windows aided with the "Unix for Windows utilities" (https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/)  - which has grep.exe, cut.exe, tr.exe and tee.exe.

Comment: Besides the fact that you did not at all show and own efforts to solve the task, you do not even show how the output format looks like. Is the format guaranteed, may values/lines be missing in some blocks? Please [edit] your question and post your coding attempts as well as an output file sample that suits the input data sample!

Answer (score 0):

bitcoin-cli getblock 000000006a625f06636b8bb6ac7b960a8d03705d1ace08b1a19da3fdcc99ddbd | findstr "\"hash\" \"size\" weight height">outfile.csv

should select those lines and output to the indicated csv file.

`findstr` is documented - see `findstr /?` from the prompt.

`\"` escapes `"` to indicate that it's a literal character to be located, not end-of-string.

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not show any efforts on your own and you did not even clearly specify how the output data format should look like, I decided to write a script, because of the nice challenge:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_LOGFILE=%~1"
set "_HEADER=%~2"
set _ITEMS="hash","size","weight","height"

for /F "delims==" %%C in ('2^> nul set $') do set "%%C="
for /F %%C in ('^< "%_LOGFILE%" find /C /V ""') do (
    < "%_LOGFILE%" (
        if defined _HEADER echo(%_ITEMS%
        set "FLAG="
        for /L %%I in (1,1,%%C) do (
            set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if "!LINE!"=="{" (
                endlocal
                set "FLAG=#"
            ) else if "!LINE!"=="}" (
                endlocal
                if defined FLAG (
                    for %%T in (%_ITEMS%) do (
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                        if defined FLAG (
                            < nul set /P ="!$COL[%%~T]!"
                        ) else (
                            < nul set /P =",!$COL[%%~T]!"
                        )
                        endlocal
                        set "FLAG="
                    )
                    set "FLAG=" & echo/
                )
            ) else if defined FLAG (
                for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%K in ("!LINE!") do (
                    endlocal
                    for %%T in (%%K) do set "LEFT=%%~T"
                    for %%T in (%%L) do (
                        if "%%T"=="[" (
                            call :ARRAY RIGHT %%I %%C
                        ) else (
                            set "RIGHT=%%T"
                        )
                    )
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    for /F "delims=" %%S in ("$COL[!LEFT!]=!RIGHT!") do (
                        endlocal
                        set "%%S"
                    )
                )
            ) else (
                endlocal
            )
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B


:ARRAY  rtn_string  val_index  val_count
    set "#REF=%~1"
    set "IDX=%~2" & set "CNT=%~3"
    set "%#REF%=,"
:ARRAY_LOOP
    set /A "IDX+=1"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "LINE=" & set /P LINE="" || (
        if !IDX! GTR !CNT! goto :ARRAY_QUIT
    )
    for %%T in (!LINE!) do (
        endlocal
        if not "%%T"=="]" (
            set "ITEM=%%~T"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            for /F "delims=" %%S in ("!%#REF%!!ITEM!,") do (
                endlocal
                set "%#REF%=%%S"
            )
            goto :ARRAY_LOOP
        )
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
:ARRAY_QUIT
    for /F "delims=" %%S in (^""!%#REF%:~1,-1!"^") do (
        endlocal
        set "%#REF%=%%S"
    )
    exit /B
```

Given that your sample log data is stored in the file `.\test-log.txt`, the script is saved as `convert-log-text-to-csv.bat` in the current directory, and you call it by the command line...:

```cmd
convert-log-text-to-csv.bat ".\test-log.txt"
```

..., the output looks as follows:

> ```cmd
> "000000006a625f06636b8bb6ac7b960a8d03705d1ace08b1a19da3fdcc99ddbd",215,860,2
> ```

If you want a header, provide an arbitrary second command line argument, like...:

```cmd
convert-log-text-to-csv.bat ".\test-log.txt" HEAD
```

..., leading to the output:

> ```cmd
> "hash","size","weight","height"
> "000000006a625f06636b8bb6ac7b960a8d03705d1ace08b1a19da3fdcc99ddbd",215,860,2
> ```

To write the output to a CSV file `.\test-log.csv`, change the command line to the following...:

```cmd
convert-log-text-to-csv.bat ".\test-log.txt" > ".\test-log.csv"
```

..., or:

```cmd
convert-log-text-to-csv.bat ".\test-log.txt" HEAD > ".\test-log.csv"
```

To append the returned data to a (potentially) existing CSV file, simply change `>` to `>>`.

Answer (score -2):

Single source file converted into an accruing single csv output:

```
cat file.txt | grep "\"hash\""   | cut -f2 -d ":" | tr -d "\r\n" | tee -a csv_file.csv
cat file.txt | grep "\"size\""   | cut -f2 -d ":" | tr -d "\r\n" | tee -a csv_file.csv
cat file.txt | grep "\"weight\"" | cut -f2 -d ":" | tr -d "\r\n" | tee -a csv_file.csv
cat file.txt | grep "\"height\"" | cut -f2 -d ":" | tr -d "\r\n" | tee -a csv_file.csv
echo: >>csv_file.csv
```